# Prove that a function that satisfies the following condition is a polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Assume that $ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ is a continuous function, such that

$$ f\left(x\right)=\frac{f\left(x-r\right)+f\left(x+r\right)}{2} $$

For any $ x\in \mathbb{R} $ and any $ r>0 $.

Prove that $ f $ is a polynomial of degree at most 1.

This may be related to complex analysis because I got this question in my complex analysis course, I guess I just cant see it.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/786888/42969

Comment: @MartinR In my case it is not an interval. Assumig $ f $ is a polynomial in any closed interval, is it enough to conclude that $ f $ is a polynomial in  $ \mathbb{R} $?

Comment: If it's a linear function on $[-a,a]$ for every $a>0$ then yes, it's a linear function on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @saulspatz I dont think this is holds. I was asked to prove that $f $ is a polynomial. In the proof that I was given here, the function $f$ depend on the interval we are working on, and therefore we can only assume $f$ is partwise linear in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: If the condition holds on $\mathbb{R}$ then it holds in every interval in $\mathbb{R}$, right?

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, but thr opposite is more subtle argument, not any condition that holds on any closed segment holds also on $ \mathbb{R} $

Comment: But this one does, trivially.  If $f$ agrees with a linear polynomial $p$ on $[-3,3]$ and also with linear polynomial $q$ on $[-4,4]$ then $p=q$, right?

Comment: An easy way to do this directly is to replace $f$ with $f-f(0)$ which  satisfies same, so assume wlog $f(0)=0$ hence $f$ odd ($x=0$) and then we get $f(x)=\frac{f(x+r)-f(r-x)}{2}=f(r)-f(r-x)$ which obviously implies the result using continuity - weaker conditions are actually enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem becomes easier if you define
$$
g(x) = f(x) - f(0).
$$
Observe
$$
g(x) = f(x) - f(0) = \frac{f(x-r)+f(x+r)}{2} - f(0) = \frac{g(x-r)+g(x+r)}{2}
$$
and
$$
g(0) = 0.
$$

**Statement 1:** for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $r>0$:
$$
g(nr) = ng(r).
$$
**Proof:** by induction

- seed the induction $2 g(r) = g(0) + g(2r)$ thus $g(2r) = 2g(r)$.
- step of the induction: $2 g([n-1]r) = g([n-2]r) + g(nr)$ thus $g(nr) = (2[n-1]-[n-2])g(r) = ng(r)$

Induction follows **QED**

**Statement 2:** for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$:
$$
g(nx) = ng(x).
$$
**Proof:** observe $2 g(0) = g(-r) + g(r)$, thus $g(-r)=-g(r)$ for any $r>0$. Now consider any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$
$$
g(nx) = g(\text{sign}(x)\text{sign}(n)|n||x|)
= \text{sign}(x)\text{sign}(n) g(|n||x|)
= \text{sign}(x)\text{sign}(n) |n| g(|x|)
= \text{sign}(n) |n| g(\text{sign}(x)|x|)
= n g(x).
$$
Case $x=0$ is trivial. **QED**

**Statement 3:** for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $x \in \mathbb{R}$:
$$
g\left(\frac{n}{m}x\right) = \frac{n}{m}g(x).
$$
**Proof:** consider $m \in \mathbb{Z}$
$$
g(x) = g\left(\frac{m}{m}x\right) = m g\left(\frac{1}{m}x\right)
$$
thus
$$
g\left(\frac{1}{m}x\right) = \frac{1}{m} g(x)
$$
the rest is obvious. **QED**

**Statement 4:** for any $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ we can write $g(x) = kx$ for some $k \in \mathbb{R}$.

**Proof:** consider $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, thus $x = n/m$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $m \in \mathbb{Z}$
$$
g(x) = g\left(\frac{n}{m}\right) = \frac{n}{m} g(1) = g(1) x.
$$
We define $k = g(1)$. **QED**

**Statement 5:** for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we can write $g(x) = kx$ for some $k \in \mathbb{R}$.

**Proof:** since $f$ was continuous, $g$ is as well. By continuity and statement 4 we conclude $g(x) = kx$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ not only $\mathbb{Q}$ ($\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$). **QED**

**Final statement:** $f(x) = k x + b$.

**Proof:** define $b = f(0)$ and use statement 5. **QED**